# CSS Media query for handling orientation does not work in Android emulator

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have an HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
    <Title>Android Orinetation test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="or"></div>
    <script>
        function handleOrientationValue(mql)
        {
            alert("Handler called");
            if(mql.matches) 
            {
                document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "Orientation : portrait";
            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "Orientation : landscape";
            }
        }
        var portraitOrientationCheck = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");
        portraitOrientationCheck.addListener(handleOrientationValue);
        handleOrientationValue(portraitOrientationCheck);
    </script>
</body>
```

This HTML works fine when I try that in Chrome Browser. To change the orientation, we can resize the browser. If the width of the browser is more than Height, it is land scape otherwise it is portrait.

I tried to create an android application using this file by opening it in the web view and ran the application in the emulator. It is not working then.

In http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia it is said that matchMedia is supported in Android Browser. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

I have shared the Android project in https://www.dropbox.com/s/mlbysk3s7tj81mk/orientationtest.zip

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: It's a hack but you can try to use `if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){//...}`

Comment: @Fab You mean instead of (mql.matches), I could use the check you suggested? The issue is that the handleOrientationValue() function itself is not invoked when the orientation is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with the "*resize*" listener.

```
<html>
<head>
    <Title>Android Orientation test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="or"></div>
    <script>

    function handleOrientation() {
        if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
            document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "Orientation : portrait";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "Orientation : landscape";
        }
    }
    var a = window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        handleOrientation();
    }, false);

    handleOrientation();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The resize listener works fine in Android. But if we try the same code in iOS, the height and width does not change when the orientaion changes.

Is there a way to use orientaion listener itself. I tried window.matchMedia() API and matchMedia.js polyfill. but does not seem to work on Android. If matchMedia polyfill works, that also would be great.